# Is this even possible?

Tags: python

Recently, my brother introduced me to the wonders of python; ever since i have been enjoying this aspect of programming, however i seem to have a problem.
I have created a file consisting of names of people, each name having a number of results. I have created code which would figure out the average of each of the persons 3 results, it works.

Here is my file-

```
 - Tim
 - 3
 - 9
 - 6
 - Bill
 - 7
 - 5
 - 3
 - Steve
 - 10
 - 9
 - 8
```

Unfortunately, these results are from a game, and the user can play the game as many times as possible, therefore if their are four results in one person, my code would not work. For this reason, i would like to know how i can get the last three results from each person. I do not want to alter my code, as i believe it would be easier to create new code that will pop the users first result, and append their new result.

For example if Tim's new result is 2, the file should look like-

```
 - Tim
 - 6 
 - 7
 - 2
```

I do not want to alter the format of my file for example,csv; as my code only works in the same format of the file.I have converted the file into a list in python, so that i can pop and append the results in a sequence, here is my code.

```
file = open('Results.txt', 'r')
lines = file.read().splitlines()
print (lines)
```

I know their is not much code but for some reason i don't understand how to pop the first number of person and append their new score.I have been researching and i believe i need to use a 'if statement' with the index of the file in order to pop the results in a sequence and save the new result in a sequence, however i am completely stuck. Am i on the right tracks? Will converting the file into a list work? I enjoy coding but honestly, i feel like giving up. Can anyone please help me? Any help will be deeply appreciated.Thank You!

Comment: If you're not sure what an *if statement* is, you should probably set aside your current task and spend some time learning more about programming.  This is a great resource for learning Python:  http://www.diveintopython.net

Comment: i understand what an if statement is, however i'm unsure of the code of the statement, i'm just stuck and asking for help. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) will allow you to specify the maximum number of elements to retain.

```
>>> import collections
>>> foo = collections.deque(maxlen=3)
>>> foo.append(1)
>>> foo.append(2)
>>> foo.append(3)
>>> foo
deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
>>> foo.append(4)
>>> foo
deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but i am a beginner, how would i incorporate this so my program would work? I am researching collection.deque, but is their anything that you could say that can help me, from getting confused by researching?

Comment: Instead of reading the items into a list, read them into a deque.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I believe I can do this, I shall continue my program tomorrow, you have made my program attainable

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
print(lines[-3:])
```

Comment: i have already tried list slicing, but i cant figure out a sequence, that will slice the last number of name( if their are more than 3 results)